# How do i extend multiple classes in Android Studio?

Tags: android, class

I am following a tutorial on YouTube yo request permissions
at runtime. I created a Java Class called: AbsRuntimePermission and i have to extend it on my MainActivity.
But i also have to extend AppCompatActivity, is there a way to extend both?
Because if i try that it will give me a error:

```
Class cannot extend multiple classes
```

And i am trying like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, AbsRuntimePermission {
```

I hope someone can help me out, i am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0pqDwsCEfs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't extend more than one classes in JAVA.

You can extend `AbsRuntimePermission` with `AppCompatActivity`

and extend  `MainActivity` with `AbsRuntimePermission`. Because `AbsRuntimePermission` is already extended with `AppCompatActivity` which means `MainActivity` is also extended with `AppCompatActivity`.

```
public class AbsRuntimePermission extends AppCompatActivity{
}

public class MainActivity extends AbsRuntimePermission {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. Use interfaces instead (implements ... ).

Update:
There is already an answer above to your particular problem: you can extend Application class in your abstract class and then extend it by your activity.

Comment: Correct. Also, "has a" is often a better design than "is a". Consider just having your AvsRuntimePermission class just be a member of your MainActivity class instead of using inheritance.